# Are the values of these two functions equal?

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f$ defined on the nonnegative reals such that 
$f(x)=x$ for all nonnegative $x$
and the function $g$ defined on the nonnegative reals such that $g(0)=0$, $g^{\prime}(3)=987654321$, and $g^{\prime}(x) = 1$ for all nonnegative $x \neq 3$.

Does $f(x)=g(x)$ for all nonnegative $x$? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

No because $f'(3)=1 $and $g'(3)\ne 1$

Comment: Why exactly does this necessarily mean $f(x) \neq g(x)$ for some $x$?

Comment: If the values were the same then the derivatives would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

f'(3) = 1 and g'(3) is not 1.

This argument is correct if considering your question of whether it's applicable for '*all*' non negative values of *x* and that both functions are continuous and differentiable. However, more is required to say with certainty that it does not hold for '*some*' values of *x*.

The function g can be a piecewise function defined such that the derivative behaves in such way.
The distinction can be thought of with this example :

g(x) = x + c for all non negative real  except x = 3
This gives g'(x) = 1 for all non negative real values and f is not equal to g for all x for non zero values of c and for 'some' x for c = 0 ( since we don't know how g is defined for x = 3 by the nature of it's derivative )

Comment: What if $g$ is continuous?

Comment: That is not probable since the derivative behaves in such a way. Irrespective, Then the argument holds, except for the case of g(x) = x + c wherein, f is not equal to g for all the values

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for all nonnegative $x\ne 3,$ it follows that these functions coincide for all nonnegative real numbers different from $3.$ So our conclusion depends solely on checking the functions at the point $x=3.$ Then, it is obviously clear that $f(3)\ne g(3).$

Thus the functions do not entirely coincide on the given domain.